# Remove specific strings only if the names begin with them

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have cell values containing full names.

I would like to replace/remove the following characters from the whole Excel sheet:

```
Al
Al-
EL
El-
```

But the fact is I want them to be replaced only if the word start with that characters. For example:

> Alorfze - (remove "al")
>   arALfzi - (do not remove "al")
>   Ibrahim El-ketoob (remove "el-")

Moreover, It will only replace this characters if the matched word has more than 4 characters.

Comment: Post what you've tried or how far you've gotten.  SO isn't really for open ended questions like this.

Comment: Tell us what did you try so far. Additionally, please do not include tags in question titles. Titles must briefly explain what is your problem or concern, I'd advise you for next question to provide better titles to your questions.

Comment: seems to be a reasonable question; certainly vague and lacking any attempt to write the code themselves but apart form that I can't see the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Replacing text in all cells of a workbook implies using VBA code. Put the following code in a module (use Alt-F11 to open the VBA editor, then Insert--> Module to add a module, then copy/paste the following text; go back to the worksheet, select "Macros", run `replaceStuff` and watch the magic.  A few things to note:

1. The use of `Option Explicit` : always a good idea, guards against typos etc
2. `Option Compare Text` : means that "al" = "AL" - in other words, removes case sensitivity from comparison (usually what you want)
3. The array of strings to check for is a variable: makes it easy to change what you want to edit
4. By setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of the macro, and setting it `True` at the end, you speed up execution and save some blinking of the spreadsheet during execution
5. Using the `Mid()` function with just two parameters means "until the end of the string" - shorter, and more robust, than either using "a big number" or something like `len(c.Text) - l`

**EDIT** modified to replace search strings even if they occur at the start of a WORD, but not the start of the CELL

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub replaceStuff()
Dim getRidOf
getRidOf = Array("AL-", "AL", "EL-", "EL")
Dim c As Range
Dim s, sp
Dim f As Integer
Dim flag As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
  c.Select
  If Len(c.Text) >= 4 Then
    For Each s In getRidOf
      flag = False
      f = InStr(1, c.Text, s)
      If f > 0 Then
        ' check that it's part of a four letter word or more
        sp = InStr(f, c.Text, " ")
        If sp > f + 3 Or (sp = 0 And f <= Len(c.Text) - 3) Then
          If f = 1 Then
            flag = True
          Else
            If Mid(c.Text, f - 1, 1) = " " Then ' it is at the start of a word
              flag = True
            End If ' at start of word
          End If ' f = 1
        End If ' four letter word
      End If ' f > 0
      If flag Then
        c.Value = Replace(c.Value, s, "")
        Exit For
      End If
    Next s
  End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Tested:

```
ibrahim el-ketoob   ibrahim ketoob
ibrahimel-ketoob    ibrahimel-ketoob
abel        abel
aleb        eb
al bob      al bob
belbo       belbo
bol al bel      bol al bel
el al       el al
allele      lele
alele       ele
elalle      alle
alelle      elle
```

Note - I added the string "EL-" as another search string so `el-ketoob` would turn into `ketoob` and not `-ketoob`.

Note also - things are processed "in order". Right now there is an `Exit For` statement after the first string is replaced (this means: "do not compare against other strings in the `getRidOf` array for this particular cell; we're done, go to the next cell"), so only the first match is replaced (and only one match - so `alfred al-hamsy` would be turned into `alfred hamsy` since `al-` gets processed before `al`, and then it stops. If you remove the `Exit For` (add an apostrophe `'` in front of it to turn it into a comment), it would turn into `fred hamsy`, but `alfred alhamsy` would turn into `fred alhamsy` since only the first `al` is replaced.

I hope you can figure out from here how to change things to fit your needs.

Comment: It won't work for me it doesn't change anything :(
ibrahim el-ketoob (for instance doesn't changed), I follow the steps of running the micro exactly. Hope to get your help

Comment: I see the problem - as written this only checks the start of the text in the cell, not the start of every word. Will update later today.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove first two letters in words which start with characters "al", "el", "al-", or "el-" and these words need to be greater than 4 characters.

I will assume you have a list of names under column A, with many rows as observations (A1, A2, A3, etc.).

This example would work for cell A2. Then, all you need to do is to drag the formulas to the other cells:

Transform name to lower case. Type in B2:

```
=LOWER(A2)&" "
```

Get the first name (word) if it has more than one word. C2:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)))
```

Number of characters in the first word. D2:

```
=LEN(C2)
```

First two letters in first word. E2:

```
=IF(D2>4,(LEFT(C2,2)),"")
```

Output 1. F2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(E2="al",SUBSTITUTE(C2,"al","",1),IF(E2="el",SUBSTITUTE(C2,"el","",1),C2)),"-","")
```

Retrieve the second word/name. G2:

```
=TRIM(MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2),100))
```

Number of characters in the second word. H2:

```
=LEN(G2)
```

First two letters in second word. I2:

```
=IF(H2>4,(LEFT(G2,2)),"")
```

Output 2. J2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(I2="al",SUBSTITUTE(G2,"al","",1),IF(I2="el",SUBSTITUTE(G2,"el","",1),G2)),"-","")
```

Final product (list of complete names, after trimming). K2

```
=IF(J2="",PROPER(F2),PROPER(F2&" "&J2))
```

Here are 8 words as examples and their derived formula outputs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    s = "Al-"
    t = "Al"
    u = "EL"
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Len(r.Text) > 4 Then
            If Left(r.Text, 3) = s Then
                r.Value = Mid(r.Text, 4, 9999)
                GoTo skipit
            End If
            If Left(r.Text, 2) = t Or Left(r.Text, 2) = u Then
                r.Value = Mid(r.Text, 3, 9999)
            End If
        End If
skipit:
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It won't work for me it doesn't change anything :(
ibrahim el-ketoob (for instance doesn't changed), I follow the steps of running the micro exactly. Hope to get your help